# JS Toggle Div Height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here a little script to change the height of my Div but actually it's only getting smaller. How can I toggle it to get it back higher again?

```
$( ".div1" ).click(function() {

$(".div2").animate({
    height: ($(this).height() == 40) ? 10 : 40
}, 200);

});
```

Comment: I can't comment, but I think you'll might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577252/making-jquery-animate-divs-to-grow-in-size) out. EDIT: Hm. trival answer converted to comment. Didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that `$(this)` refers to `$( ".div1" )` not `$( ".div2" )`

```
   $( ".div1" ).click(function() {

    $(".div2").animate({
        height: $(".div2").height() == 40 ? 10 : 40
    }, 200);

    });
```

Full Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrRboZ

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if-then` statement:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var boolean = false;
  $(".div1").click(function() {
    boolean = !boolean;
    if (boolean) {
      $(".div2").animate({
        height: "+=20px"
      }, 200);
    } else {
      $(".div2").animate({
        height: "-=20px"
      }, 200);
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">Foo</div>
<div class="div2">Bar</div>
```

Also, I would use a relative `height` so it changes back to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit obscure, but you can use modular arithmetic.

Notice that:

```
(40 + 30) % 60 == 10
(10 + 30) % 60 == 40
(40 + 30) % 60 == 10
```

and so on

So, in other words, you can just do

```
$( ".div1" ).click(function() {
    $(".div2").animate({
        height: ($(".div2").height()+30)%60
    }, 200); 
});
```

PS: beware of the use of this, if you are not clear you may be referring to a different object, in this case, $(".div1")

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggleClass:

```
 .div2{height:40px;}
 .div2.smaller{height:10px;}


 $('.div1').click(function(){$('.div2').toggleClass('smaller');});
```